# getting rid of blank space between table rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get rid of the red background between the images here. 
How can I do this using css?

```
 <table style="background-color:red; padding:0;margin:0;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="/graphics/susSlogan.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="/graphics/susSlogan.gif">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[image]

Comment: inspect your web page, the browser console should show you what the space is composed of and set that to 0

Comment: Always hard to tell without a [mcve]. You could try `border-spacing: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the padding on the `<td>` elements. So something like:

```
td{
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<table cellpadding="0"></table>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp

or you can use

```
td {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp